# Creating a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me!     (Code provided below) ([Data Here](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/AllDeepSoilData.zip?raw=true))

**I am trying to average the first 3 columns and insert it as a new column labeled 'Topsoil'. What is the best way to go about doing that?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
raw_data = pd.read_csv('all-deep-soil-temperatures.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df_all_stations = raw_data.copy()
df_selected_station.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace=True);
df_selected_station_D=df_selected_station.resample(rule='D').mean()
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.dayofyear
mean=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').mean()
mean['Day']=mean.index
#mean.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
mean['avg3col']=mean[['5 cm', '10 cm','15 cm']].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new column'] = (df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3'])/3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `apply` method in the following way:

```
mean['Topsoil'] = mean.apply(lambda row: np.mean(row[0:3]), axis=1)
```

You can read about the `apply` method in the following link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

The logic is that you perform the same task along a specific axis multiple times.

Note: It is not wise to call data-structures in names of functions, in your case it might be better be `mean_df` rather the `mean`

Comment: `apply` are loops under the hood, for performance reason is best dont use it if exist vectorized alterantives.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I didn't know that this is the case. I will try to avoid this issue.

Comment: This is prototype for avoid it - arithmetic operations

Comment: @jezrael so just to make it clearer, for arithmetic operation `iloc` will always be faster and more appropriate?

Comment: No, It means `df.apply(np.mean, axis=1)` is slowier like `df.mean(axis=1)`, iloc here is for selecting only.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)  for select by positions - first 3 columns with `mean`:

```
mean['Topsoil'] = mean.iloc[:, :3].mean(axis=1)
```